# java program to loop back to start

Tags: java

I am trying to get this program to loop back and start again when the user wants to try another word. I have tried a while loop but couldn't figure it out. I am a newbie to programming so any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PEX5{

    public static void main(String[] theArgs){

        int numLetters;
        char fromStack;
        char fromQueue;
        int charCount;

        String x;

        UnboundedStackInterface<Character> myStack = new LinkedStack<Character>();
        UnboundedQueueInterface<Character> myQueue = new LinkedUnbndQueue<Character>();

        System.out.println("Enter a word to check for Palindrome");

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        x = keyboard.nextLine();

        int i;
        numLetters = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
            Character ch = x.charAt(i);

            numLetters++;

            myStack.push(ch);
            myQueue.enqueue(ch);
        }

        charCount = 0;

        while(charCount <= numLetters) {

            fromStack = myStack.top();
            myStack.pop();
            fromQueue = myQueue.dequeue();

            if(fromStack != fromQueue)
                System.out.println("Not Palindrome");

            if(fromStack == fromQueue) {
                charCount++;
                System.out.println("Palindrome");
            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to try another? (Y = yes  N = no): ");
            x = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems straight forward. A `while (true)` loop going from before prompting the user for input and going to after processing their input should do the trick.  What did you try and what problems did you have?

Comment: Better design is create new method and make recursive call from conditional statement.

Comment: Where is the `while` loop you mentioned that you tried and what problems were you having?

Comment: @amicngh If you feel that is "better design" please post an answer and elaborate more on why. As it stands your comment is arguably incorrect and definitely misleading.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc If you're going to make code formatting edits please go all the way and do it properly. Man, this is like a day care today.

Comment: @JasonC Did you see the edit I made?

Comment: I had the while loop at the beginning but never could get it to loop all the way back to the start.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Yes, I saw it. Check out http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/10au/indent.html too, it's good for SO, indents with spaces. I have a lot of success with it here.

Comment: Guy, you should pick an answer or close the question or something. Peace ;)

Comment: Are you gonna pick an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You could put everything into a while loop like this:

```
boolean isRunning = true;
String tryAgain = "";

while (isRunning) {

 // All your code you have in your example.

 // Ask user if he wants to retry with a scanner.
 tryAgain = <use scanner here>;
 if (tryAgain.equals("no") || tryAgain.equals("No") ) isRunning = false;

}
```

Or

```
String tryAgain = "";

while (true) {

 // All your code you have in your example.

 // Ask user if he wants to retry with a scanner.
 tryAgain = <use scanner here>;
 if (tryAgain.equals("no") || tryAgain.equals("No") ) break;

}
```

Obviously you need to adjust code so it asks the user with a system out println, you might wanna do more checks if he writes yes or nothing at all etc. but you have to do a little yourself. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is create an outer loop to persist the game until someone wants to quit.  There are a few ways to do this, one way I've done it in the past is like this:

```
boolean willContinue = true;
do {
    // Game code here

    // prompt user to continue (or quit)
    if(keyboard.nextLine().startsWith("N")) willContinue = false;

} while (willContinue)
```

You could get the same results by making it a while (True) loop, and having a No response call break; instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this, add a do while and ask user to enter something to continue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {
public static void main(String[] theArgs)

{   int numLetters;
    char fromStack;
    char fromQueue;


    int charCount;
    String x;
    UnboundedStackInterface<Character> myStack = new LinkedStack<Character>();
    UnboundedQueueInterface<Character> myQueue = new LinkedUnbndQueue<Character>();
    String ch;
    do{
    System.out.println("Enter a word to check for Palindrome");
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    x = keyboard.nextLine();



    int i;
    numLetters = 0;



    for(i = 0;i<x.length();i++)
    {

    numLetters++;

    myStack.push(ch);
    myQueue.enqueue(ch);
    }


     charCount = 0;

    while (charCount<=numLetters)
    {

        fromStack = myStack.top();
        myStack.pop();
        fromQueue = myQueue.dequeue();

        if(fromStack != fromQueue)
          System.out.println("Not Palindrome");

       if(fromStack == fromQueue)
        {charCount++;
          System.out.println("Palindrome");
        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to try another? (Y = yes  N = no): ");
        x = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        }

    System.out.println("To continue enter 'y'");
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    ch = keyboard.nextLine();

    }while(ch=="y");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code. Here are some fixes for them:

- Do your input stream declarations using a "try-with-resources" statement. Every single input/output element should be wrapped this way; it makes it far easier to reuse code later.
- You need to add javadoc comments to your code.
- Encapsulate the palindrome checking in its own function. By refactoring out the decision logic from the input/output logic, you can make the code much clearer and more concise. Write a method to fill this signature:

  ```
  public static boolean isPalindrome(String word)
  ```
- Simplify the palindrome checking algorithm. All you need to do is check that the word is itself reversed. Nothing fancy. For instance, you can do this:

  ```
  public static boolean isPalindrome(String word){
      return String.valueOf(Arrays.reverse(word.toCharArray())).equals(word);
  }
  ```

  This is not only easier to read, it is actually faster too.
- Change the prompt structure. Do they *really* need to tell you every time that they want to input another word? I would recommend using the 'leave blank to quit' exit type. The prompt could then be:

  ```
  System.out.print("Enter a word (leave blank to quit):");
  ```
- Use a [loop-and-a-half](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/patterns/plopd/loops.html#loop-and-a-half) to accomplish the prompt cycle, instead of inventing your own inferior loop pattern:

  ```
  public static void main(String [] args) {
      try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in), PrintWriter out = System.out){
          while(true){
              out.print("Enter a word (leave blank to quit):");

              String word = in.nextLine()
              if(in.isEmpty()) break;

              out.printf("%s is%s a palindrome.%n",
                      word, isPalindrome(word)?" not":"");
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  All this code accomplishes the exact same thing as what you wrote, but is more concise, clearer, and faster.

Comment: He's a beginner, your gonna scare him to death. ;)

Comment: @ObedMarsh I added some line breaks to make the main loop more clear.

Comment: @ObedMarsh Although I really can't understand how this could possibly be scarier than what he wrote...