# How to loop block of code in Java programming

Tags: java, loops

I am writing code to display an array of numbers in ascending order. I have completed the first part which is the actual commands to get the array. The second part is that I have to make the program initialize after it has arranged an array of numbers. Here is my code.

```
package ascendingorder;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ascending_Order 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n, temp;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
        n = s.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            a[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
            {
                if (a[i] > a[j]) 
                {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Ascending Order:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.print(a[n - 1]);
    }
}
```

When the code is compiled and executed, the program prompts the user to enter the array size and on entering it, the program then asks the user to enter the elements of the array. After that, the user presses enter and the program displays the result in ascending order.

After that the program is supposed to loop back and prompt the user to enter arrays size, followed by elements and so on. Also, the program is supposed to terminate when the user enters a value like 'n' or 'x'. Kindly help me with this part as I don't have any idea or how to place the for loop in order to loop the block of code from 'System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");'. Thank you.

Comment: This some homework? https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Learn about [while loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you have the program taking nextInt so if you entered the chars it would create an exception, you should instead use nextLine and then check/parse it.
As for the loop, a simple while loop would work, and don't forget to close the scanner at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String in;
    int temp, n;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
    in = s.nextLine();
    while (!in.equals("x") || !in.equals("n")) {
        n = Integer.parseInt(in);
        int a[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Ascending Order:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.print(a[n - 1]);
        in = s.nextLine();
    }
    s.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the below link can be helpful

[[java program to loop back to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224188/java-program-to-loop-back-to-start][1])

```
boolean isRunning = true;
String tryAgain = "";

while (isRunning) {

 // All your code you have in your example.

 // Ask user if he wants to retry with a scanner.
 tryAgain = <use scanner here>;
 if (tryAgain.equals("no") || tryAgain.equals("No") ) isRunning = false;

}
```

Or

```
String tryAgain = "";

while (true) {

 // All your code you have in your example.

 // Ask user if he wants to retry with a scanner.
 tryAgain = <use scanner here>;
 if (tryAgain.equals("no") || tryAgain.equals("No") ) break;

}
```